# Best way to pass an Button onClick back to main activity?

Tags: android, gridview, button, callback

I have a super TestUI application. It has a gridview with buttons in them.

I want word of the button click to be passed back to the main Activity, so that it can update its state.

Sadly the buttons steal the clicks. So the typical:

```
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(TestUI.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Does not get called.

Instead in the adapter definition:

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button gridItem;

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        gridItem = new Button(mContext);
    } else {
        gridItem = (Button) convertView;
    }
    gridItem.setText("button " + String.valueOf(position));
    gridItem.setClickable(true);
    gridItem.setFocusable(false);
    gridItem.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position, mContext));

    return gridItem;
```

Which is backed with a class MyOnClickListener that implements the OnClickListener interface. However if I do it this way I still need a call back to the main activity, somehow it needs to know that something was done as it controls the program state.

So what is the best way to update the "root" class/activities' state from a button click?

I know this a basic OO question but I mostly write in ASM and C so I frankly just don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, your getView method is inside the adapter class. But the adapter gets a copy of the "context", which your getView method has access to. Context is a super-class of all Activities and Services. Through this object you can do many of the basic operations of an Activity. From your example, I understand that you would like to show a toast. This can be done using

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //usual getView stuff goes first

    gridItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

So in short, your MyOnClickListener class needs to used the mContext variable for interacting with the root activity.

**Edit**
I realized that I made a mistake in the above answer. I looked at the sample on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html and realized that you aren't restricted to using Context. You could use something like

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public int a = 0;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private MyActivity myAct;
    public ImageAdapter(MyActivity c) {
        myAct= c;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //usual getView stuff goes first

        gridItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public onClick(View v){
                myAct.a = position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that is what you wanted to do.

Comment: I can do Toast this is fine. I did that exactly as you say. I want to set a public variable in the main activity. Say it has 

     public void setFlagVar(int theFlag){ this.privateFlag = theFlag}

Comment: That is I want to call a public method in the main activity? I can't unless it is static. Okay fine. There are "Handlers" but such a mechanism is wildly complex for all I want to do. If the buttons are textViews I can do it the first way without layer on layer of classes and call backs...

Or I can just abandon Gridview and use LinearLayout + Scroll + some vectors to contain the buttons... 

However to state the problem clearly you have a Main Activity, it creates a GridView of buttons, you want the button clicks to change a local variable in the main activity or otherwise send a callback.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize from the example I could pass anything other than context! I was looking at that very example... I think all is well with the world... I can call any public function back in the main object by passing it as you did, which is all I wanted.

Comment: Just careful about passing activity reference to objects, or creating non Static innerclasses. Memory leaks are veeeery close , so i don't think this is the optimal solution you need.

Comment: agreed... this strategy is prone to memory leaks... but this strategy is very "clean" in the code that it produces

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have 2 onClickListeners. From the `onItemClickListener` you have to the main activity can't you do all the work you need to do? Is a necessary for the adapter to do the `MyOnClickListener` work?

You can set the gridItem.setOnClickListener from the main activity. No need to create a new ListenerObject every time.

You just need a xml to inflate to getView containing a Button

```
  <Button android:text="Handle me"
     android:id="@+id/btnHandleMe"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="buttonHandler"
     android:clickable="true">
```

and create this function to your activity.

```
public void buttonHandler(View v) {
        // Do your stuff here that new MyOnClickListener(position, mContext) whould do.
    }
```

You can get the position of the row/column that this button is populated in the list/grid by adding a tag to the adapter.

In getView add

```
 gridItem.setTag(position)
```

and to retreive it from buttonHandler

```
if(v.getTag instance of Integer)
int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
```

So now you handle all clicks from the activity and by default the activity is notified.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully follow that. The reason there are two click handlers in the above post is because the first way does not work...

As far as inflating with an XML file I think that is off limits... This is a programmaticly generated interface that it gets off of Bluetooth from a remote system... No need to go into that, but the number of objects is unknown at runtime.

As written with buttons in a gridView the onItemClickListener is not called because the button listens for the click and absorbs it.

Comment: then i would create a custom eventListener that i bind to the gridView and fired on button click. http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/. You said the "right way". The fast way would be to call a custom function of the activity from the adapter ,but then you have to use static or pass the entire activity you the adapter, which is not the right technic. If there are no other suggestions by me or another go with the "Create your own eventlistener" method

Comment: Thanks. I am sure that could work. I hope there is a still robust but less complex solution. I likely will use LinearLayout + Buttons directly for the moment unless someone gives me a better way to use the gridView as a container for buttons with Callback... There are many related posts about ListView and buttons FWIW. I haven't found a solution yet.